# How do I test is a variable is of a variable type in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to do something like the following in C#:

```
public bool ValidType(Type type)
{
    return _someVar is type;
}
```

C# doesn't seem to support this syntax though; the item to the right of "is" appears to have to be an absolute type name, not a reference to a type.

I have discovered that the following code seems to work:

```
return _someVar.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(type) ||
    _someVar.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type) ||
    _SomeVar.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

I don't understand what `IsAssignableFrom` does, other than it seems needed in some type comparisons as `IsInstanceOfType` and `IsSubclassOf` don't seem to match all cases properly.

Is this really the best way to test of a variable is of a type, referred to by another variable, or is there a simpler syntax that I've missed?

Comment: there's always the `typeof` operator, and the `as` keyword

Comment: @Dan-o, "as" has the same problem as "is", in that it can only be used with type names. typeof() won't reveal whether _someVar is an instance of a derived type of type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsAssignableFrom` is enough, no need for the other two tests but you are calling it the wrong way round. Here’s the correct way:

```
public bool ValidType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsAssignableFrom(_someVar.GetType());
}
```

> I don't understand what IsAssignableFrom does

Actually, it does exactly what the name tells you: it tests whether a variable of a given type is assignable from a value of another type.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not true, I do need the others. IsAssignableFrom only return true if "type" is the type of _someVar. If it's a parent type of _someVar, it returns false. I need the exact same functionality as "is", which works for parent types too.

Comment: @David Ah, you need to invert the arguments!

Comment: Ah, I should have looked my closely at your code. I hadn't thought to do type.IsAssignableFrom(), I'd been doing _someVar.IsAssignableFrom(). That does indeed do what I need. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Konrad has mentioned `IsAssignableFrom` is enough for your test.

**Determines whether an instance of the current Type can be assigned from an instance of the specified Type.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

You won't need the other two checks because, in those cases, `IsAssignableFrom` would also be true.